# Frames of Reference in a Rotational System

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, inertial-frames

Imagine two concentric rings with different diameters. One is spinning within the other. There is a small gap between the outer diameter of the inner ring and the inner diameter of outer ring.

From the frame of reference of the outer ring, the inner ring is spinning and tends to expand radially outward, *closing* the gap. From the frame of reference of the inner ring, the outer ring is spinning and tends to expand radially outward *expanding* the gap.

Where is the hole in my thought process that results in this contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in thinking that both observers will each conclude they themselves are stationary.

Rotating frames of reference are non-inertial - accelerometers can  detect their movement. Observers would easily discover that they are rotating and not stationary.

In a non-inertial frame of reference, the laws of physics have to be formulated differently using fictional forces to account for effects like the coriolis effect and the centrifugal effect.

Answer (score 1):

What you are forgetting is that in a rotating frame an observer will feel a [fictitious force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force). In the frame of the observer on the inner ring the observer feels an outward force that stretches the inner ring towards the outer one. Likewise an observer on the outer ring feels an outward force that stretches the outer ring away from the inner one.